# Customizing Autofac's component resolution / Issue with generic co-/contravariance

Tags: c#, customization, resolution, autofac, generic-variance

First, sorry for the vague question title. I couldn't come up with a more precise one.

Given these types:

```
                                                     { TCommand : ICommand }
       «interface»                   «interface»    /
      +-----------+         +----------------------/----+
      | ICommand  |         | ICommandHandler<TCommand> |
      +-----------+         +---------------------------+
            ^               | Handle(command: TCommand) |
            |               +---------------------------+
            |                              ^
            |                              |
      +------------+            +-------------------+
      | FooCommand |            | FooCommandHandler |
      +------------+            +-------------------+
            ^
            |
   +-------------------+
   | SpecialFooCommand |
   +-------------------+
```

I would like to write a method `Dispatch` that accepts any command and sends it to an appropriate `ICommandHandler<>`. I thought that using a DI container (Autofac) might greatly simplify the mapping from a command's type to a command handler:

```
void Dispatch<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
{
    var handler = autofacContainer.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
    handler.Handle(command);
}
```

Let's say the DI container knows about all the types shown above. Now I'm calling:

```
Dispatch(new SpecialFooCommand(…));
```

In reality, this will result in Autofac throwing a `ComponentNotRegisteredException`, since there is no `ICommandHandler<SpecialFooCommand>` available.

Ideally however, I would still want a `SpecialFooCommand` to be handled by the closest-matching command handler available, ie. by a `FooCommandHandler` in the above example.

Can Autofac be customized towards that end, perhaps with a custom registration source?

---

**P.S.:** I understand that there might be the fundamental problem of co-/contravariance getting in the way (as in the following example), and that the only solution might be one that doesn't use generics at all... but I would want to stick to generic types, if possible.

```
ICommandHandler<FooCommand> fooHandler = new FooCommandHandler(…);
ICommandHandler<ICommand> handler = fooHandler;
//                                ^
//              doesn't work, types are incompatible
```

Comment: +1 for the way you represent your question.

Comment: Daniel's suggestions below are a good approach, in any case the `in` parameter modifier is necessary. It is possible to support contravariant `Resolve()` using an `IRegistrationSource` as you have guessed. I've put them together in the past but don't have the code with me, if I can hack one up I'll post it for you.

Comment: I like to question the usefulness of this in your particular situation. When you create a special command sub type, how can the handler for the base type ever handle that command correctly, since it won’t see the extra properties that the sub command adds? Wouldn’t the cases were it would execute correctly be exceptional? In that corner case it would be easy to define a `SpecialFooCommandHandler` that wraps on an `ICommandHandler<FooCommand>` does nothing more than calling `this.wrapped.Handle(command)` in its `Handle` method.

Comment: @Steven more commonly this approach is used to handle events rather than commands. In that context, calling say `IHandler<IAuditableEvent>` in addition to `IHandler<AddressChangedEvent>` can be useful (where `AddressChangedEvent` implements the interface.)

Comment: @Nicholas: I agree. For events this might indeed be useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Not really a fair answer, as I've extended Autofac since you posted the question... :)*

As per Daniel's answer, you'll need to add the `in` modifier to the `TCommand` parameter of `ICommandHandler`:

```
interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Autofac 2.5.2 now includes an `IRegistrationSource` to enable contravariant `Resolve()` operations:

```
using Autofac.Features.Variance;

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
```

With this source registered, services represented by a generic interface with a single `in` parameter will be looked up taking variant implementations into account:

```
builder.RegisterType<FooCommandHandler>()
   .As<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();

var container = builder.Build();
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<SpecialFooCommand>>();
```

Both calls to `Resolve()` will successfully retrieve the `FooCommandHandler`.

If you can't upgrade to the latest Autofac package, grab the `ContravariantRegistrationSource` from http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac/Features/Variance/ContravariantRegistrationSource.cs - it should compile against any recent Autofac build.

Comment: +1. Thanks once again for the great work on Autofac. I'll update to the new version. I'll also check out the implementation of `ContravariantRegistrationSource` as soon as I get around to it!

Comment: Wow, I hadn't seen the contravariant features. That's amazing! Definitely going to be using these.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is not possible without own coding.
Basically, you are asking the following: If the type I tried to resolve isn't found, return another type that can be converted to it, e.g. if you try to resolve `IEnumerable` return a type that is registered for `ICollection`.
This is not supported.
One simple solution would be the following:
Register `FooCommandHandler` as a handler for `ICommandHandler<SpecialFooCommand>`. For this to work, ICommandHandler needs to be [contravariant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx):

```
interface ICommand { }

class FooCommand : ICommand { }

class SpecialFooCommand : FooCommand { }

interface ICommandHandler<in T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Handle(T command);
}

class FooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<FooCommand>
{
    public void Handle(FooCommand command)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<FooCommandHandler>()
       .As<ICommandHandler<SpecialFooCommand>>()
       .As<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();
var container = builder.Build();
var fooCommand = new FooCommand();
var specialCommand = new SpecialFooCommand();
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>().Handle(fooCommand);
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>().Handle(specialCommand);
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<SpecialFooCommand>>().Handle(specialCommand);
```

BTW: The way you are using the container, you apply the [Service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). This should be avoided.

Comment: Nice answer. FWIW, I haven't found any way to avoid Service Locator when dispatching to generic handlers like this. I'd love to hear about any alternatives you know of. Cheers!

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for your answer. This would actually work well in my case, and it's so simple that I completely overlooked it. +1 The only thing this requires is knowledge of the command handler class.

Answer (score 3):

I like to add an alternative approach, which also works without C# 4.0 variance support.

You can create a special decorator / wrapper that allows executing a command as its base type:

```
public class VarianceHandler<TSubCommand, TBaseCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TSubCommand>
    where TSubCommand : TBaseCommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TBaseCommand> handler;

    public VarianceHandler(ICommandHandler<TBaseCommand> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void Handle(TSubCommand command)
    {
        this.handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

With this in place, the following line of code would allow you to handle `SpecialFooCommand` as its base type:

```
builder.Register<FooCommandHandler>()
    .As<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();

builder.Register<VarianceHandler<SpecialFooCommand, FooCommand>>()
    .As<ICommandHandler<SpecialFooCommand>>();
```

Note that the use of such `VarianceHandler` works for most DI containers.