# Autofac: Hiding multiple contravariant implementations behind one composite

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac, covariance

I was triggered by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010236/customizing-autofacs-component-resolution-issue-with-generic-co-contravarianc) about (.NET 4.0) covariance and contravariance support for Autofac, and now I'm trying to achieve something similar, but without any luck.

What I am trying to achieve is configure Autofac in such way that when I resolve a single concrete `IEventHandler<TEvent>` (for the sake of demonstration using `container.Resolve`, but normally of course using constructor injection), Autofac will return me a `MultipleDispatchEventHandler<TEvent>` that wraps all registered event handlers that are assignable from the requested handler.

In other words, when I write this:

```cs
var handler = container
    .GetInstance<IEventHandler<CustomerMovedEvent>>();

handler.Handle(new CustomerMovedEvent());
```

With respect to the application design (given below), I'd expect a `MultipleDispatchEventHandler<CustomerMovedEvent>` to be returned that wraps both a `CustomerMovedEventHandler` and a `NotifyStaffWhenCustomerMovedEventHandler`.

Here is the application design:

```cs
// Events:
public class CustomerMovedEvent { }

public class CustomerMovedAbroadEvent : CustomerMovedEvent { }

public class SpecialCustomerMovedEvent : CustomerMovedEvent { }


// Event handler definition (note the 'in' keyword):
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent> 
{
    void Handle(TEvent e);
}

// Event handler implementations:
public class CustomerMovedEventHandler
    : IEventHandler<CustomerMovedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(CustomerMovedEvent e) { ... }
}

public class NotifyStaffWhenCustomerMovedEventHandler
    : IEventHandler<CustomerMovedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(CustomerMovedEvent e) { ... }
}

public class CustomerMovedAbroadEventHandler
    : IEventHandler<CustomerMovedAbroadEvent>
{
    public void Handle(CustomerMovedAbroadEvent e) { ... }
}
```

This is the definition of the `MultipleDispatchEventHandler<TEvent>`, defined in the Composition Root:

```
// A composite wrapping possibly multiple handlers.
public class MultipleDispatchEventHandler<TEvent>
    : IEventHandler<TEvent>
{
    private IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>> handlers;

    public MultipleDispatchEventHandler(
        IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>> handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public void Handle(TEvent e)
    {
        this.handlers.ToList().ForEach(h => h.Handle(e));
    }
}
```

This is my current configuration:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Note the use of the ContravariantRegistrationSource (which is 
// available in the latest release of Autofac).
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IEventHandler<>).Assembly) 
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>));

// UPDATE: I'm registering this last as Kramer suggests.
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MultipleDispatchEventHandler<>))
    .As(typeof(IEventHandler<>)).SingleInstance();

var container = builder.Build();
```

With the current configuration, the application fails during the call to `Resolve`, with the following exception:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: Circular component
>   dependency detected:
>   MultipleDispatchEventHandler'1[[SpecialCustomerMovedEvent]] ->
>   IEventHandler'1[[SpecialCustomerMovedEvent]][] ->
>   MultipleDispatchEventHandler'1[[SpecialCustomerMovedEvent]].

Now the question is of course: how can I fix the configuration (or the design) to support this?

Comment: Are we required to fix this using autofac? Or are you just trying to figure out how various IoC containers resolve this particular case?

Comment: @thekip: You've probably seen my question history :-). While I would be interested to see how to do this with containers such as Castle Windsor, StructureMap and Unity, my interest is currently with Autofac, since that container recently added explicit support for contravariance. I might add questions for those containers in the future, so please don’t answer it for other containers. And of course I know how to do this with Simple Injector ;-)

Comment: Of course, your example scenario is easily solved if you separate an `IEventPublisher<TEvent>` from the `IEventHandler<TEvent>`. This may be a good idea anyway, depending who you ask - having a separate interface for event raisers vs. event consumers lowers coupling. But then there's no composite, and I assume you're more interested in the Composite than Customers moving around :)

Comment: @default: Can you update / append your answer to show me this. I'm very interested to see this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for `IEventRaiser<T>` by @default.kramer. Just for the record, since the linked answer doesn't provide any code, and the configuration for this scenario is a bit less than intuitive because of the generic types involved:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(...)
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>)))
        .Select(i => new KeyedService("handler", i)));

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MultipleDispatchEventHandler<>))
    .As(typeof(IEventHandler<>))
    .WithParameter(
         (pi, c) => pi.Name == "handlers",
         (pi, c) => c.ResolveService(
             new KeyedService("handler", pi.ParameterType)));
```

Comment: The way you did that KeyedService registration is awesome! I need to revisit some of those `As` overloads. I tested this out and it works as expected after I made a few obvious edits.

Comment: Cool - thanks for checking it out. We need a C# syntax checker implemented in JavaScript for Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @Nicholas: The line `(c, pi) => pi.Name == "handlers"` does not compile, since the `pi` argument is of type `IComponentContext` and does not contain a `Name` property. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @Steven Apparently my edits didn't go through - just change it to `(pi, c)`. Also, the arguments are reversed on the last `KeyedService` constructor.

Comment: @Nicholas: That's sneaky. The `ContravariantRegistrationSource` must be registered *before* the other registrations. Otherwise all will fail. I added this line to your answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Nicholas: Since this answer allows us to stick to the design given in the question, I mark this as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks both for the edits. @Steven, registration order shouldn't matter here; if you happen to reproduce it I'd be interested to know as it would indicate a bug I think. Cheers!

Comment: @Nicholas: I can reproduce it. Were do you want me to report this bug with example code?

Comment: @Steven http://autofac.org issue tracker would be great- thanks for taking the time! :)

Comment: @Nicholas: See [issue 341](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=341).

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to make this a separate answer instead of modifying my other one. This one solves the example scenario without using a composite.

### Working Code

I added a `static int handleCount` to each of the event handlers for testing purposes, like this:

```
public class CustomerMovedEventHandler
    : IEventHandler<CustomerMovedEvent>
{
    public static int handleCount = 0;
    public void Handle(CustomerMovedEvent e) { handleCount++; }
}
```

Here's a passing test that demonstrates that the events are going where they should:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterSource(new Autofac.Features
    .Variance.ContravariantRegistrationSource());

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IEventHandler<>).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>));

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EventRaiser<>))
    .As(typeof(IEventRaiser<>));

var container = builder.Build();

Assert.AreEqual(0, CustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(0, NotifyStaffWhenCustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(0, CustomerMovedAbroadEventHandler.handleCount);

container.Resolve<IEventRaiser<CustomerMovedEvent>>()
    .Raise(new CustomerMovedEvent());

Assert.AreEqual(1, CustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(1, NotifyStaffWhenCustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(0, CustomerMovedAbroadEventHandler.handleCount);

container.Resolve<IEventRaiser<CustomerMovedAbroadEvent>>()
    .Raise(new CustomerMovedAbroadEvent());

Assert.AreEqual(2, CustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(2, NotifyStaffWhenCustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(1, CustomerMovedAbroadEventHandler.handleCount);

container.Resolve<IEventRaiser<SpecialCustomerMovedEvent>>()
    .Raise(new SpecialCustomerMovedEvent());

Assert.AreEqual(3, CustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(3, NotifyStaffWhenCustomerMovedEventHandler.handleCount);
Assert.AreEqual(1, CustomerMovedAbroadEventHandler.handleCount);
```

You can see I'm using an `IEventRaiser<TEvent>` instead of a composite `IEventHandler<TEvent>`. Here's how it looks:

```
public interface IEventRaiser<TEvent>
{
    void Raise(TEvent e);
}

public class EventRaiser<TEvent> : IEventRaiser<TEvent>
{
    List<IEventHandler<TEvent>> handlers;

    public EventRaiser(IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>> handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers.ToList();
    }

    public void Raise(TEvent e)
    {
        handlers.ForEach(h => h.Handle(e));
    }
}
```

### Design Thoughts

Avoiding the composite `IEventHandler` sure makes our work at the composition root easier. We don't have to worry about recursive composition or making sure the composite is the default implementation. But we added a new interface `IEventRaiser` which might look redundant. Is it? I think not.

**Raising an event and handling an event are two different things.** `IEventHandler` is an interface that has to do with handling events. `IEventRaiser` is an interface that has to do with raising events.

Imagine that I'm a piece of code that wants to raise an event. If I ask the IoC for a single `IEventHandler` I am introducing coupling that I don't need. I shouldn't need to know about that `IEventHandler` interface. I shouldn't be asking anyone to `Handle` my event. All I want to do is `Raise` it. Handling may or may not happen on the other side; it is irrelevant to me. I'm selfish - **I want an interface created solely for me and my need to raise events.**

As an event raiser, I intend to raise an event. As an event handler, I intend to handle an event. We have two different intents, so we should have two different interfaces. Just because we could use the same interface and a composite doesn't mean we should.

The [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) seems to be more about splitting fat interfaces into thinner ones (see also [Role Interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html)). In our case, we don't have a fat interface, but I think we're doing something similar - "Interface Segregation by Intent".

**One more thing**

In writing this answer I almost articulated a design idiom that I think many of us are familiar with, but I don't think we have standard terminology for it.

"Type C Interface" - frequently Consumed, rarely Implemented. A "service" interface. For example, `IEventRaiser` or `ICustomerRepository`. These interfaces probably have only one implementation (maybe decorated a bit) but they are consumed all over the place by code that wants to Raise Events or Save Customers.

"Type I Interface" - frequently Implemented, rarely Consumed. A "plugin" interface. For example, `IEventHandler<TEvent>`. Consumed in only one place (the `EventRaiser`) but implemented by many classes.

The same interface should not be both a Type C and a Type I. This is another reason to separate the `IEventRaiser` (Type C) from the `IEventHandler` (Type I).

I'm thinking that the composite pattern is only applicable to Type C interfaces.

Please edit or comment if there is standard terminology for what I've called "Type C" and "Type I" interfaces.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but nice answer nonetheless ;-)