# Registring Concrete Types That Implement Variant Generic Interfaces With Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac, covariance

Consider following strucure as a registration subject with Autofac 3.0.0:

```
class Something
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
}

class SomethingGood : Something
{
    private int _good;
    public int GoodResult {
        get { return _good + Result; }
        set { _good = value; }
    }
}

interface IDo<in T> where T : Something
{
    int Calculate( T input );
}

class MakeSomethingGood : IDo<SomethingGood>
{
    public int Calculate( SomethingGood input ) {
        return input.GoodResult;
    }
}

class ControlSomething
{
    private readonly IDo<Something> _doer;
    public ControlSomething( IDo<Something> doer ) {
        _doer = doer;
    }

    public void Show() {
        Console.WriteLine( _doer.Calculate( new Something { Result = 5 } ) );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to register concrete type MakeSomethingGood and then resolve it by contravariant interface.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register( c => new MakeSomethingGood() ).As<IDo<SomethingGood>>();
builder.Register( c => new ControlSomething( c.Resolve<IDo<Something>>() ) ).AsSelf();

var container = builder.Build();
var controller = container.Resolve<ControlSomething>();
```

... and `Resolve` fails because no components found for `IDo<Something>`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing Autofac's component resolution / Issue with generic co-/contravariance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010236/customizing-autofacs-component-resolution-issue-with-generic-co-contravarian)

Comment: The ContravariantRegistrationSource as mentioned in the other question is still available in 3.0.0.

Comment: @Steven - it's quite similar, however I'm trying to ask different question here.

Comment: @Steven - In my example, `Resolve` fails because Autofac didn't manage to find services by contravariant interface, i.e. finding  `IDo<SomethingGood>` by `IDo<Something>`

Answer (score 1):

You register an `IDo<SomethingGood>` and try to resolve an `IDo<Something>`. How is that ever supposed to work? For this to work, `IDo<T>` should be defined as covariant: `IDo<out T>`.

Since `IDo<in T>` is defined as contravariant (using the `in` keyword), you can't simply assign an `IDo<SomethingGood>` to `IDo<Something>`. This won't compile in C#:

```
IDo<SomethingGood> good = new MakeSomethingGood();

// Won't compile
IDo<Something> some = good;
```

And that's why Autofac can't resolve it, even with the `ContravariantRegistrationSource`.