# Autofac - injecting based on generic interface and concrete type

Tags: .net, generics, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have the following interface

```
public interface ICheckEvaluator<in TCheck> where TCheck : ResourceCheck
```

that needs to be injected with the following implementation:

```
public class OutageCheckEvaluator : ICheckEvaluator<OutageCheck>
```

Can someone provide an advice as to how this can be done?  OutageCheck inherits from ResourceCheck:

```
public partial class OutageCheck : ResourceCheck
```

The following method didnt work:

```
builder.RegisterType<OutageCheckEvaluator>().As<ICheckEvaluator<OutageCheck>>();
```

as Autofac receives ICheckEvaluator(ResourceCheck) to implement and cannot match it to ICheckEvalutor(OutageCheck)

Appreciate any advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resolve those `Evaluators` by using e.g. reflection.

```
public class AutofacTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<OutageCheckEvaluator>().As<ICheckEvaluator<OutageCheck>>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        var listOfChecks = new List<ResourceCheck> { new OutageCheck() };
        foreach (var check in listOfChecks)
        {
            var interfaceType = typeof(ICheckEvaluator<>).MakeGenericType(check.GetType());
            var evaluator = container.Resolve(interfaceType);
            Debug.WriteLine(evaluator);
        }
    }
}

public interface ICheckEvaluator<in TCheck> where TCheck : ResourceCheck { }

public class OutageCheckEvaluator : ICheckEvaluator<OutageCheck> { }

public class OutageCheck : ResourceCheck { }

public class ResourceCheck{}
```

but the problem is that since generic parameter is contravariant you cannot do any of those casts

```
var test = new OutageCheck() as ICheckEvaluator<ResourceCheck>;
var evaluator = container.Resolve(interfaceType) as ICheckEvaluator<ResourceCheck>;
```

Is there any special need you have `ICheckEvaluator<in TCheck>` instead of `ICheckEvaluator<out TCheck>`?

Comment: I was/am getting an error that OutageCheckEvaluator cannot be cast to ICheckEvaluator<ResourceCheck>.

Comment: Could you provide more code samples to reproduce that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, my issue is that I dont resolve objects like you did in the test.  I have a List<ResourceCheck> that I run through, and for every one of them, I instantiate a factory that tries to create an Evaluator object.  I dont know the type of each ResourceCheck until the code runs.

Comment: I did have to use contravariance, but found this post to help with casting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010236/customizing-autofacs-component-resolution-issue-with-generic-co-contravarian